# Type of singularity of sum

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I know type of some singularity of functions $f(z) $ and $g(z) $. For examle $f $ has removable singularity at $0$ and $g $ has a pole at $0$. Can I conclude anything about singularity of function $f (x)+g (x) $ from that?

Comment: Removable singularities don't really count as singularities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call $n \in \mathbb{Z}\cup\{-\infty\}$ the order of $0$ as zero of $f$ that is $$f(z)=z^nh(z)$$ where $h$ is holomorphic and does not vanish at zero. (Note that the order is neagtive iff $0$ is a pole of $f$.

Likewise, call $m$ the order of $0$ as zero of $g$.

If $m\neq n$ the order of $0$ as a zero of $f+g$ is $min(m,n)$.

For instance if $n<m$ you have $$f(z)+g(z)=z^n(h(z)+z^{m-n}u(z))=z^n w(z)$$

where $w(0)=h(0)\neq 0$.